# PHP Mail not receiving?

Tags: php, email, sms

So I am creating something for my website that sends you a text with all of your transactions at the end of the month. It sends one text for each transaction (all at once.) I am using PHP `mail()` function to send the texts (number@vtext.com.) The average amount of transactions is around 100, so it sends 100 texts/emails at once via a loop.

It works, but the phone will receive like 50 or so and then stop receiving them then like a few hour later it will receive maybe 20 more, then stop again, and so on. Is this the phones problems? Or my servers? Has the server actually sent all of the mail and the phone is just having trouble receiving it?  Thanks.

Comment: the texts messages get queued before sending, probably thats causing the delay.

Comment: If you get them at all then it's all in how the phone receives data from the server. This will be a setting in your phone, but may not be largely configurable

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, because it's sort of an interesting quesiton, but do people really appreciate receiving 100 texts? It sounds like the worst thing ever. "Wow! I just got 100 unsortable texts! My phone has been beeping at me for an hour! This is great! And I love using my phone to document my transaction logs... it's so easy to read and do analysis on! Plus, there's a good chance I pay for texts after a fairly low threshold! Fantastic!". User friendliness aside you're going to hit interal mailqueue limits and likely trigger SPAM blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is the effect of some spam protection algorithm inside your mail server.

Have a try looking at the emails headers, if you are lucky that spam protection tool added some information to the message that might give a hint.